# Retrieving node in classic ASP

Tags: xml, soap, asp-classic

Classic ASP isn't my first language and I need to bug fix something. I have highlighted the problem but a little stuck.

I have the following SOAP response, the Root var is loading the data fine:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>  
<checkVatResponse xmlns="urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:vies:services:checkVat:types">    
<countryCode>GB</countryCode>
<vatNumber>xxxxxxx</vatNumber>
<requestDate>2012-12-05+01:00</requestDate>
<valid>true</valid>
<name>XYZ LIMITED</name>
<address>Jon Street
London</address>
</checkVatResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Now I need to extract the 'valid node. I have tried the following but to no avail

```
Set Root = oXmlDom.documentElement 

response.write(Root.SelectSingleNode("SOAP:Envelope/SOAP:Body/checkVatResponse/valid").text)
response.write(Root.SelectSingleNode("SOAP:Envelope/SOAP:Body/urn:checkVatResponse/valid").text)    
response.write(Root.SelectSingleNode("//urn:valid").text)
```

Show me the obvious problem please!

Comment: As a work around for any future visitors please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351460/get-a-only-string-from-soap-response-in-classic-asp

Comment: oXmlDom.selectSingleNode("//soap:Envelope/soap:Body/checkVatResponse/valid").text it is case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a couple of things here. Firstly, XML is case-sensitive, so you need to do your Select statements like `soap:Body` rather than `SOAP:Body`.

Secondly, the .`documentElement` function returns the first element of the XML, which in this case is `soap:Envelope`, so since you are using `SelectSingleNode` from the `Root` object you created, then this is telling the parser to look for the following:

```
<soap:Envelope>
  <soap:Envelope>
    <soap:Body>
```

So just leave off the first branch in your SelectSingleNode statements, like:
`response.write(Root.SelectSingleNode("soap:Body/checkVatResponse/valid").text)`

Hope that helps.